# How to change the entries field of a ListView programmatically with string resources

Tags: android, listview

I have a simple list view defined in my xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mode_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:entries="@array/mode_array_generic" />
```

I have three different string arrays defined in my string.xml (one being "mode_array_generic") and I'd like to choose which string array is loaded when my fragment starts based on some passed parameter.

Is there a clean simple way to redirect the "entries" field to a different string resource during "onCreateView"?

Comment: You can't alter the `<ListView>`'s `entries` value at runtime, if that's what you mean. However, all that attribute does is cause `ListView` to load that array from `Resources`, and set an `ArrayAdapter` constructed from that array and the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` layout. You could easily do that yourself.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. that was enough of a hint to find what I needed to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MikeM.'s comment gave me the hints I needed.  Here's my solution for future reference.

Get the string array based on the parameter using a switch or if-else block:

```
String[] modeList = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.mode_array_generic);
```

Then create an ArrayAdapter with it:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, modeList);
```

(the "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1" as the resource ID for a layout whas where I was stuck)

Than just set the adapter on the ListView:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mode_list);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```